# Trying to use UIKit in my project but gives error

Tags: ios

Hey I'm using objective C

```
import<UIKit/UIKit>
```

it gives me the error and doesn't allow me to continue the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using ojective c but you are using uikit
you should use

```
#import<foundation/foundation.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`! You forgot to prefix `#`!